# sql query / getting latest entry based on two different conditions

Tags: mysql, join

this is my table structure:

```
[id] [senderid] [recipientid] [message] [datetime]
```

i want to get latest entry (based on datetime) for each conversation (for certain user), result should be (for own userid 1):

```
435 | 1 | 67 | how are u? | timestampnow
```

next result (after response):

```
436 | 67 | 1 | fine thanks | timestamplater
```

confused how to do query / join correctly. i tried somethink like:

```
SELECT * FROM messages MSG

INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(id) MAXDATE,recipientid,senderid 
 FROM messages
 GROUP BY recipientid,senderid) MSG2

ON MSG.recipientid = MSG2.recipientid
AND MSG.id = MAXDATE
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.*
from (
    select max(id) as id from (
        select max(id) as id, recipientid as user_id
        from messages
        where senderid = ?
        group by recipientid
        union all
        select max(id) as id, senderid as user_id
        from messages 
        where recipientid = ?
        group by senderid
    ) sub
    group by user_id
) sub
join messages m using(id)
```

The innermost subquery will return up to two `id`s per conversation (the `id` from last sent message and the `id` from last received message). The outer subquery will grab the highest of the two `id`s. Then the result is joined with the `messages` table to return the corresponding rows.

(Replace `?` with the given user ID)

A shorter way could be:

```
select m.*
from (
    select max(id) as id
    from messages
    where ? in (senderid, recipientid)
    group by case when senderid = ? then recipientid else senderid end
) sub
join messages m using(id)
```

But that one might be slower.

Answer (score 0):

Firts build a query with the conditions:

```
SELECT recipientid, MAX(date) mdate
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY recipientid
```

The use it as a subquery:

```
SELECT a.[id], a.[senderid], a.[recipientid], a.[message], a.[datetime]
FROM yourTable a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT recipientid, MAX(date) mdate
                FROM yourTable
                GROUP BY recipientid) b ON b.recipientid = a.recipientid
                                        AND a.datetime = b.mdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sub select there

It might be as simple as that:

```
SELECT id, senderid, recipientid, message, MAX(datetime) as datetime
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY recipientid;
```

Comment: I's definitely not as simple as that.

Comment: right, my bad - overlooked that "conversation" is bidirectional, 
though it's pretty simple anyway